# Passing information about types of object from UI to data layer

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, user-interface

I have a data object which has a base class with three derived classes,

```
public enum ModelType
{
   A,
   B, 
   C
}
public abstract class Parent
{
   protected ModelType type; 
}

public class ChildA: Parent
{
    private new ModelType type = ModelType.A;
}

public class ChildB: Parent

public class ChildC: Parent
```

The same `type` field is in the other 2 children with corresponding `ModelType`s.

I have another layer between the forms that has some higher level additional information about the data object and an instance of `Parent()`. I am trying to simplify the problem a lot so I apologise if I am not being clear and have not given enough information.

```
public enum UIModelType
{
   A,
   B, 
   C,
   None
}
public class DataObject
{
    private Parent someData;
    private UIModelType type;
}
```

The fields have getter and setter properties.

The UI only communicates with the `DataObject` class and cannot see the lower level `someData` object.

Now at some point during the UI (which is a wizard to fill in the information in the data objects), the user can select `A`, `B` or `C`. My problem is how to communicate this information without too much code repetition. Right now I have an enum between the UI and `DataObject` class. So if user selects `A`, it assigns a data type as `A` using the enum. The `DataObject` class now instantiates the `someData` object with `ChildA()`. The problem is to communicate between the `DataObject` and `someData` object I have another enum with A, B and C to communicate the type.

Would it be healthier to use typeof instead, although I have read that that is not the best way to go.

I need to do many equality checks with the data type (ABC) from the UI all the way to the lower level data object and hence I had thought enums is the fastest way but it doesn't feel right to have so many enums of the same type in different classes. Am I missing something very obvious here?

Comment: Please show some code, you've abstracted too much with your story. Besides, I see a child both has an *is-a* and an *has-a* relation with its parent, is there any link between those relations?

Comment: What is wrong with typeof() ?

Comment: Perhaps rather than abstracting the problem causing ambiguity, you could provide a simple example which demonstrates what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have added some more code. An example would be if the user decides to change the model type, I need to perform some validation to make sure whether the change is permitted or not.

Comment: You should look into GetType() / typeof() and maybe the Factory design pattern.

Comment: Would the is-a and has-a be a better option than typeof? I would like to eliminate at least one of the enums

Comment: @nEm - You should be able to eliminate the need to have `enum`s which identify the type by using `typeof` or `Object.GetType`. The `enum`s are redundant since your objects already know *what* they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `typeof` or `enum`, you could use `is`.

```
private Parent someData = new ChildA();

if (someData is Parent) { } // Returns true.
if (someData is ChildA) { } // Returns true.
if (someData is ChildB) { } // Returns false.
```

However, if I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you're doing these checks because you need to continually downcast the `someData` object to provide functionality for the `DataObject` class that depends on the type of `someData`. If this is the case, you might want to consider refactoring your code, as repeated downcasting can can make code difficult to read and defies some traditional concepts of object-oriented programming.

Edit:

Ok, I think I understand your question better, now. You're looking for a better way of creating children of the `Parent` object (i.e. using the factory pattern) than by using an `enum`.

You could create the instance dynamically based on the type name:

```
var typeName = GetTheTypeTheUserWants();
var type = System.Type.GetType(typeName, false, true);
if (type == null) throw new Exception();

var someData = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Parent;
if (someData == null) throw new Exception();
```

Using an `enum` might be easier, but this method allows you to create new subclasses of `Parent` without updating your `enum`.

If I still missed the point of your question, sorry.

Comment: I never actually instantiate the parent class and once I create childA, it remains childA for the scope of that data object. If the user changes the model, then I need to create a new child object. The DataObject class only contains information like the directory the child will be serialised into and the filename etc.

Comment: Well basically I had a switch case statement checking the  enum type sent by the UI, and then creating the corresponding child object. My problem came up when I sometimes need to do validation like (if childA) then do this... I would have to do an is or typeof everytime

Answer (score 0):

Just use 'typeof' and be done with it.  It sounds like you are only using enums because of some tiny increase in performance that you *might* get.  Just go with whatever produces the easiest to read / maintain code (typeof in this case).

I don't think that you have to worry about performance in your wizard because the slowest part is going to be the user selecting what type of object they want.

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of `ModelType`. You're just creating another way to represent information you already have, which will just be annoying to maintain.

In your `DataObject` class, your `UIModelType` could go away too. Wherever you thought you were going to use it could probably be replaced with:

```
if (this.someData is ChildA) {

} else if (this.someData is ChildB) {

} ...
```

Comment: I was going to use it in the UI and if I do the above that means my lower level data objects (`someData`) will be exposed to the UI class which I do not want.